# return all records within user input interval before user input date

Tags: sql, datetime

I need to return all records whose date is within the specified time before the user input date(Most likely its going to be a week but  it can be anything), I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
     where T.postdate >= DateADD(day, @Length, @StartDate)
```

where @Length and @StartDate are input by the user in a stored procedure but its return date from months ago..

Comment: "from months ago" - where does months come in?

Comment: I have this: where T.postdate <= DateADD(day, -7, 2014-10-7), and its returning data from years ago still

Comment: try this: `T.postdate >= DateADD(day, -7, '2014-10-7')` with quotes, otherwise  2014 - 10 -7=1997, is a math expresion, not a date

Comment: @user3825831 your comment "where T.postdate <= DateADD(day, -7, 2014-10-7)" indicates give me everything when the post date is before "2014-10-01"... so everything from 1753-01-01 to 2014-10-01  EDIT: or it might be 2014-09-30... head math

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could do something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7241b/4

```
create table test (someDate datetime)
insert into test (someDate)
select '2014-01-01'
union all select '2014-02-01'
union all select '2014-03-01'
union all select '2014-04-01'
union all select '2014-05-01'
union all select '2014-06-01'
union all select '2014-07-01'
union all select '2014-08-01'
union all select '2014-09-01'
union all select '2014-10-01'
union all select '2014-10-02'
union all select '2014-10-03'
union all select '2014-10-04'
union all select '2014-10-05'
union all select '2014-10-06'
union all select '2014-10-07'
union all select '2014-10-08'
union all select '2014-10-09'
union all select '2014-10-10'
union all select '2014-10-11'

declare @lengthInDays int, @startDate datetime

select @lengthInDays=5, @startDate='2014-10-02'

select *
from test
-- where "somedate" is after the start date minus the number of days input
where someDate >= dateadd(day, -@lengthInDays, @startDate) 
-- and where the "someDate" is not greater than the date input
and someDate < @startDate
```

Only returned result in this instance is `2010-10-01` due to it being between 5 days prior to @startDate and @startDate

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this.
WHERE T.postdate >= DATEADD(week, -@Length, @StartDate)
```